# getElementById(...) returns null unexpectedly

Tags: javascript, getelementbyid

**EDITED**: I pretty much checked dozens of articles here on this issue, but I simply can't find the problem in my code: The line (commented below) returns null, although I expect it to return the particular element I created and added above.

```js
    element2 = document.createElement("button");
    element2.innerHTML = "-";
    element2.text = rowCounter;
    element2.style.backgroundColor = 'white';
    element2.id = "kuerzer"+rowCounter; //rowCounter is an iterator variable
    ell2.appendChild(element2);
    console.log(document.getElementById(element2.id)); //returns null
```

However, I am now trying to find this element in another function like this:

```js
function structureGantData(){
      var gantData = [[]];
      for(i=0; i<document.getElementById("myTable").rows.length; i++){
        console.log("schleife");
        gantData[i][0] = document.getElementById("kuerzer",(i+1)).text; //ISSUE
```

Could anyone help me? :-)

Thanks alot!

Fabian

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you meant to call `document.getElementById("kuerzer" + (i + 1))` rather than `document.getElementById("kuerzer", i + 1)` in `structureGantData`.

Comment: Thanks for your post! I am now calling gantData[i][0] = document.getElementById("kuerzer" + (i + 1)).text; and do receive the error message jstut.html:272 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property '0' of undefined .

Comment: that suggests that `gantData[i]` is undefined; make sure you've initialized said array

Answer (score 4):

You have not added the created element to the DOM, so it cannot be found there.

You may use say [`Node.appendChild`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/appendChild) (or any other similar) method to append it somewhere first.